# Number of graphs that satisfies the property that edge weight is maximum of node values on which the edge is incident

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

I have an undirected weighted graph without multi edges. All the edge weights are whole numbers and known. I want to know in how many ways node values(node values are also whole numbers) can be assigned to the nodes such that the graph satisfies the condition that for every edge its edge weight is exactly equal to maximum of two node values this edge is incident on.

Comment: What's the context in which you encountered this task?  Are you looking for practical solutions or theoretical complexity?  What approaches have you already considered?

Comment: If the edge weights are distinct, the problem can be reduced to #2SAT: let $x_{(u,v)}=1$ mean that the weight of edge $(u,v)$ is equal to the weight of $u$, and $x_{(u,v)}=0$ mean that it is equal to the weight of $v$. Then your problem can be expressed as.a 2SAT formula, and we want to count the number of satisfying assignments.  Unfortunately #2SAT is #P-complete, so there is no efficient algorithm for it.  Perhaps you can construct a reduction in the opposite direction.